# Python: construct a larger trigonometric function based on iteration of smaller function

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

**Hello**

I have the function y = sin (x*b(i)+a(i)).
I want to create a new function f, that is a product of the n first iteration of this y-function with i as the iterator.

f = y(I=1)*y(I=2)*y(I=3)

How do I create such an f in python?

Note that b(i) and a(i) are not simple like e.g. b = I^2 and a=3i. they have if-statements in them, so as far as I understand I need to have them outside my y function. 
Lets say they are:

```
b: if i%2 == 0:
      b = I^2+2
   else
      b = 3

a: if i/3 = int(I/3):
      b = 5i
   else
      b = 0
```

The goal here is that I can just change the variable I, then get a f-function with a product of the y-functions with I iterations. Then I can use the f-function to find new values for x.

*(Hope my non-pro rambling makes sense)*

**EDIT: This code solves my problem: **

```
import math

def a(i):
    if i/3 == int(i/3):
        out = 5 * i
    else:
        out = 1 
    return out

def b(i):
    if i%2 == 0:
        out = (i^2)+2
    else:
        out = 3
    return out

def y(x, i):
    return x * b(i) + a(i)

def f(x, i):
    accum = 1
    for iterations in range(i):
        accum *= y(x, iterations + 1)
    return accum

print f(3,5)
```

Comment: Can you clarify which part you're struggling with? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you familiarize yourself with Python syntax so you can post an example of what you've tried which is running code, or at least shows the error you've run into. The code you posted will not run, as it is not Python code.

Spelling/capitalization/indentation all count.

I couldn't quite follow what you wanted, but this is as near as I can make out, and you should be able to adjust from here.

```py
def a(i):
    if i/3 = int(i/3):
      out = 5 * i
   else
      out = 0

def b(i):
   if i%2 == 0:
       out = I^2+2
   else:
       out = 3
    return out

def y(x, i):
    return x * b(i) + a(i)

def f(x, i):
    accum = 1
    for iterations in range(i):
        accum *= y(x, iterations + 1)
    return accum
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code managed to make me understand it and get a running code! Sorry for the bad explanation / syntax. I'll do more research next time. Thanks!